# Can't stubbing a query with WireMock

Tags: java, http, request, wiremock

The problem is that my query like:

```
/pc/odata/api/devices?$top=3000&$skip=0&$format=json&$expand=groups&$select=ID,Name,PrimaryIPAddress,groups/GroupPathLocation&$filter=((groups/Name%20eq%20'OI%20Inventory%20Group'))&timeout=120
```

can't use for stub with

> HTTP ERROR 500
>
> Problem accessing /__files/pc/odata/api/devices.
>   Reason:
>
> Illegal character in query at index 138:
>   /not-matched?$top=3000&$skip=0&$format=json&$expand=groups&$select=ID,Name,PrimaryIPAddress,groups/GroupPathLocation&$filter=((groups/Name
>   eq 'OI Inventory Group'))&timeout=120

The request is valid, and app works with the same query without params.

A method for stub:

```
public void initialize( Integer D_ITEM_COUNT ) {

    writedItemsFile( D_ITEM_COUNT );

        ClasspathFileSource responseFiles = new ClasspathFileSource( "." );
        dItemService = new WireMockServer( WireMockConfiguration.wireMockConfig()
                .port( D_ITEMS_SERVICE_PORT )
                .fileSource( responseFiles )
                .enableBrowserProxying( false )
                .notifier( new ConsoleNotifier( true ) ) );

        dItemService.givenThat( get( urlEqualTo( D_D_ITEMS_SERVICE_ENDPOINT ) ).
                willReturn( WireMock.aResponse()
                        .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .withBodyFile( "../" + D_ITEMS_SERVICE_RESPONSE_FILE + FILE_EXTENSION )
                        .withStatus( HttpStatus.SC_OK ) ) );
}
```

Comment: Looks like an OData query ?

Comment: @StefHeyenrath Yep